# Python set with the ability to pop a random element

Tags: python, random, set

I am in need of a Python (2.7) object that functions like a set (fast insertion, deletion, and membership checking) but has the ability to return a random value. Previous questions asked on stackoverflow have answers that are things like:

```
import random
random.sample(mySet, 1)
```

But this is quite slow for large sets (it runs in O(n) time).

Other solutions aren't random enough (they depend on the internal representation of python sets, which produces some results which are very non-random):

```
for e in mySet:
    break
# e is now an element from mySet
```

I coded my own rudimentary class which has constant time lookup, deletion, and random values.

```
class randomSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}
        self.list = []

    def add(self, item):
        if item not in self.dict:
            self.dict[item] = len(self.list)
            self.list.append(item)

    def addIterable(self, item):
        for a in item:
            self.add(a)

    def delete(self, item):
        if item in self.dict:
            index = self.dict[item]
            if index == len(self.list)-1:
                del self.dict[self.list[index]]
                del self.list[index]
            else:
                self.list[index] = self.list.pop()
                self.dict[self.list[index]] = index
                del self.dict[item]

    def getRandom(self):
        if self.list:
            return self.list[random.randomint(0,len(self.list)-1)]

    def popRandom(self):
        if self.list:
            index = random.randint(0,len(self.list)-1)
            if index == len(self.list)-1:
                del self.dict[self.list[index]]
                return self.list.pop()
            returnValue = self.list[index]
            self.list[index] = self.list.pop()
            self.dict[self.list[index]] = index
            del self.dict[returnValue]
            return returnValue
```

Are there any better implementations for this, or any big improvements to be made to this code?

Comment: why would you not just use a list and cast it  as a set when you needed set operation stuff? ...

Comment: This allows you to interleve adding elements with selecting elements without a performance penalty.  Does you real life scenario really follow this pattern?  If you can do all your adding of elements up front, you could start with a set, then cast to a list before grabbing random elements.

Comment: Because that is very very slow (runs in O(n) time) for large lists.

Comment: @GrantS:  Do you mean that the list creation is slow?  That would only need to be done once.  It's no slower than creating a list and a dictionary as you do in your class.

Comment: Lists are slow for getting into elements. If the O.P. uses "in" or any other set specific operation, using a list is not an option.

Comment: @GrantS: If you are ysing Python 2.x, for the Greater Good of all: inherit from "object", or other new style base. Do not use old style classes (by not declaring a superclass) - you can get seriously hurt with a hard to debug problem

Comment: There is no such thing as "casting a list as a set" in Python.

Comment: @pillmuncher:  I suppose you are addressing my phrase "cast to a list" above.  Perhaps cast is the wrong word, but in Python you can clearly pass a set to the list constructor and get a list.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski An aside since it's not really relevant to the original question, but using `foo.items()`, `foo.keys()` (equivalent to `list(foo)`, or `foo.values()` is cleaner, and each one has an "iter" version for use in a loop (makes an iterator instead of a list, so is a little faster) (`foo.iterkeys()`, etc).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to use the [`MutableSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) abstract base class in `collections`. Inherit from `MutableSet`, and then define `add`, `discard`, `__len__,` `__iter__`, and `__contains__`; also rewrite `__init__` to optionally accept a sequence, just like the `set` constructor does. `MutableSet` provides built-in definitions of all other `set` methods based on those methods. That way you get the full `set` interface cheaply. (And if you do this, `addIterable` is defined for you, under the name `extend`.)

`discard` in the standard `set` interface appears to be what you have called `delete` here. So rename `delete` to `discard`. Also, instead of having a separate `popRandom` method, you could just define `popRandom` like so:

```
def popRandom(self):
    item = self.getRandom()
    self.discard(item)
    return item
```

That way you don't have to maintain two separate item removal methods.

Finally, in your item removal method (`delete` now, `discard` according to the standard set interface), you don't need an if statement. Instead of testing whether `index == len(self.list) - 1`, simply swap the final item in the list with the item at the index of the list to be popped, and make the necessary change to the reverse-indexing dictionary. Then pop the last item from the list and remove it from the dictionary. This works whether `index == len(self.list) - 1` or not:

```
def discard(self, item):
    if item in self.dict:
        index = self.dict[item]
        self.list[index], self.list[-1] = self.list[-1], self.list[index]
        self.dict[self.list[index]] = index
        del self.list[-1]                    # or in one line:
        del self.dict[item]                  # del self.dict[self.list.pop()]
```

Comment: +2 if I could.  It's nice to get a set interface for so little.  And excellent advice on streamlining the implementation.

Comment: If this is the solution that the thread opener uses, I would be highly interested in a seeing the `T(setsize)` graph for both this solution and a O(N) lookup solution on a default set, with `T` being the time required for a lookup.

Answer (score 2):

One approach you could take is to derive a new class from `set` which salts itself with random objects of a type derived from `int`.

You can then use `pop` to select a random element, and if it is not of the salt type, reinsert and return it, but if it is of the salt type, insert a new, randomly-generated salt object (and pop to select a new object).

This will tend to alter the order in which objects are selected. On average, the number of attempts will depend on the proportion of salting elements, i.e. amortised O(k) performance.

Comment: +1, for the idea but I'd like to know if did test some form of this. I am not shure if salting sets would be that effective.

Comment: @jsbueno Order of insertion is known to affect the order of iteration in sets, but yes, I guess this also depends on the fine details of the hashing scheme used.

Answer (score 1):

Can't we implement a new class inheriting from `set` with some (hackish) modifications that enable us to retrieve a random element from the list with O(1) lookup time? Btw, on Python 2.x you should inherit from `object`, i.e. use `class randomSet(object)`. Also [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is something to consider for you :-)

Edit:
For getting some ideas of what hackish solutions might be capable of, this thread is worth reading:
http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Get-item-from-set-td1530758.html

Comment: You should always explicitly inherit from object if your class has no other base classes and you're not using python3 :)

Comment: Why would I inherit from set? The only way this works is with a dict which points to the index of a value in a list. It doesn't use sets at all, so I don't see how inheriting from set would help.

EDIT: Wait, I might see what you're saying. Is my use of a dict here entirely unnecessary?

Comment: No.  Inheriting from `set` would be inefficient because `random.sample` would need to iterate over the entire set making it O(n).

Comment: @GrantS: I did not mean that you should just make your `randomSet` inherit from `set`. I was thinking of an entirely different solution that bases on `set`, but somehow hacks `set` in order to access a random item. Now, I see that there is no obvious way to do so without iterating over the set.

Comment: @Jan-Philip Gehrcke Indeed. I could do it with just `set` and `list` but that makes deletion run in O(n) time (which is why the `dict` is necessary).

Comment: If you "did not mean that you should just make your randomSet inherit from set" you should change the first line of your answer and say what you mean.

Comment: @martineau: thanks for the criticism :) I've edited the answer. Almost empty words, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution from scratch, which adds and pops in constant time. I also included some extra set functions for demonstrative purposes.

```
from random import randint


class RandomSet(object):
  """
  Implements a set in which elements can be
  added and drawn uniformly and randomly in
  constant time.
  """

  def __init__(self, seq=None):
    self.dict = {}
    self.list = []
    if seq is not None:
      for x in seq:
        self.add(x)

  def add(self, x):
    if x not in self.dict:
      self.dict[x] = len(self.list)
      self.list.append(x)

  def pop(self, x=None):
    if x is None:
      i = randint(0,len(self.list)-1)
      x = self.list[i]
    else:
      i = self.dict[x]
    self.list[i] = self.list[-1]
    self.dict[self.list[-1]] = i
    self.list.pop()
    self.dict.pop(x)
    return x

  def __contains__(self, x):
    return x in self.dict

  def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.list)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "{" + ", ".join(str(x) for x in self.list) + "}"

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.list)
```

Comment: There's an error in the pop method: if x != None, i is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd implement an "ordered set" in much the same way you did - and use a list as an internal data structure.

However, I'd inherit straight from "set" and just keep track of the added items in an 
internal list (as you did) - and leave the methods I don't use alone.

Maybe add a "sync" method to update the internal list whenever the set is updated
by set-specific operations, like the *_update methods.

That if using an "ordered dict" does not cover your use cases. (I just found that trying to cast ordered_dict keys to a regular set is not optmized, so if you need set operations on your data that is not an option)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind only supporting comparable elements, then you could use `blist.sortedset`.